# Is Work done to Transfer Energy?

Tags: electromagnetic, field

The example below is for a perfect lossless circuit with no resistance for the sake of illustration only. In reality this does not exist, but again the purpose is for simplicity.

If there is 1 Joule of energy stored in a capacitor and then that capacitor is connected to a coil to transfer and then store the 1 Joule of energy into the coil's magnetic field, is this work done and if so how much work was done?

Taking it one step further, once the 1 Joule of energy is fully stored in the coil's magnetic field it then has to go somewhere. It then collapses and a diode is used to redirect the 1 Joule of energy to charge another capacitor.

What is the total amount of work that has been done in storing energy starting from the 1 Joule of energy stored in the first discharging capacitor, which is then stored in the coil's magnetic field, and then lastly ending up as stored energy in the second charged capacitor?

Comment: (about the base example) Work is the change in the amount of energy. In the closed system this amount did not change, hence no work was performed. If you look only on the capacitor, then yes. A work of 1J was performed.

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer. When you mentioned "if you only look on the capacitor", which capacitor are you referring to? The first capacitor with energy exiting or the second capacitor with the energy entering?

Comment: I was talking about the base example where only one capacitor and an inductor (if I got it correctly)

Comment: I don't think your question about the total amount of work is complete. As @EugeneSh. mentioned, one must ask work done by WHAT? (1st cap, 2nd cap, the coil, or the system). Right?

Comment: I am meaning the entire system. Starting with the 1 Joule of energy in the first discharging capacitor, and then the process of storing this 1 Joule of energy in the coil's magnetic field, and then lastly, the process of charging up the second capacitor with the collapse of the coil's magnetic field. So the energy ultimately is transferred from the first capacitor, into the coil, then out of the coil, and then finally into the second capacitor. How much work is involved in this entire process?

Comment: The question contains its answer. In this hipotetic perfect lossless circuit there are no losses, so all the transfers happens without "work", and so, without losses.

Comment: @ mguima yes but the energy has moved from one place to another, are you saying this is an instantaneous transfer of energy? Then let's say it's a lossy system and it took 'time' then there would be work done with power right?

Answer (score 4):

> The example below is for a perfect lossless circuit with no resistance for the sake of illustration only. In reality this does not exist, but again the purpose is for simplicity.
>
> If there is 1 Joule of energy stored in a capacitor and then that capacitor is connected to a coil to transfer and then store the 1 Joule of energy into the coil's magnetic field, is this work done and if so how much work was done?

In the diagram below, C1 is initially charged, and stores 1J of energy. Now we close S1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUhWXC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That puts a high voltage on D1 and L1. D1 is reverse biased so does not conduct. Current builds in L1 due to the voltage across its terminals, while VC1 the voltage on C1 falls. Eventually, VC1 gets to zero. There is now a large current flowing in L1, so VC1 tries to continue to fall, but now the (ideal) diode D1 starts to conduct, which prevents VC1 from going negative.

The voltage across L1 is zero, so the current doesn't change. As VC1 is zero, there is no energy stored in it. All the energy now resides in the current flowing through L1.

**The capacitor has done 1J of work on the inductor**

> Taking it one step further, once the 1 Joule of energy is fully stored in the coil's magnetic field it then has to go somewhere.

No, it doesn't 'have to go somewhere', it can just stay there as long as the current keeps circulating.

> ... It then collapses and a diode is used to redirect the 1 Joule of energy to charge another capacitor.

No, it doesn't just 'collapse', but we can interrupt the current, by opening S2.

When we do that, current can now no longer flow through D1, and has to be sourced from D2 instead. D2 pulls current out of C2, making its voltage negative, and the voltage across C2 increases while the current in L1 falls. Eventually the current gets to zero. D2 stops conducting, it's now reverse biassed, the voltage on L1 falls to zero, so its current stays at zero. C2 is now storing the same energy that was stored in L1, and was stored in C1.

**The inductor has done 1J of work on C2**

> What is the total amount of work that has been done in storing energy starting from the 1 Joule of energy stored in the first discharging capacitor, which is then stored in the coil's magnetic field, and then lastly ending up as stored energy in the second charged capacitor?

No work has been done opening and closing ideal switches, no work has been done heating zero resistances or making ideal diodes conduct, and no work has been done launching EM radiation from these ideal wires. In all cases, the component storing the energy has done exactly its stored energy amount of work on the component receiving the energy.

Comment: Nice answer. It is greatly appreciated along with all the work done in showing each of the processes, pun intended? Although only 1 diode is required to reroute the collapsing field in actual practice with losses, I think the final answer is perfectly correct. Are your two answers valid for 1 Watt of power as well? Joules are just energy and since the energy has done work this means it has taken 'time' which should directly translate from Joules of energy to Watts of power if the entire process took exactly 1 second of time, or is there no time involved? So 1 Watt of power has occurred? Twice?

Comment: a watt is a joule per second. With the C and L values I've shown, the transfer takes place in microseconds, so the power is in the 100kW ballpark.

Comment: Ok, let's say the circuit system had resistance in it, which of course the 1 Joule of energy becomes less, say .84 Joules and let's say it now takes 1 second, with whatever values of C and L have to be in order for the energy to be .84 Joules transferred in 1 second, so would this be .84 watts of power in that same second of time?

Comment: Draw a schematic, to show where the resistance is, then we can walk through the energy transfers.

Comment: What I mean is, if the resistance is in series with S1, then you will get a loss during the transfer, however, switches tend to have little resistance. If the resistance isin series with D1 or L1, which is much more reasonable and physical, then not only will you have a loss during the transfer, but you'll also have a continuing loss during storage, which is why inductive storage systems are so little used, they just don't have good storage times with every day materials.

Comment: Also, try to get over this power thing you have. Energy is fundamental, that's the 'cash' that the physics economy runs on. No energy, nothing happens. We define power as a convenient unit to keep track of how fast energy is moving around, energy per time. It's useful, as it tells us how thick wires should be, and helps us measure energy by measuring power and integrating over time, but it's *not fundamental*, power is always energy per time. Just keep track of the energy, and let power take care of itself.