# How much work/power is 1 Joule of energy capable of doing?

Tags: power, inductor, energy, electromagnetic, electrolytic-capacitor

I ask this question because of this question [Is .95J worth of work within 1 second Equivalent to .95W of Power?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/336654/is-95j-worth-of-work-within-1-second-equivalent-to-95w-of-power) It is not the same question and it's completely different because of the included process of swapping capacitors.

Concerning the 2nd Circuit:

The only reason I ask this question is because of capacitors C1 and C2. Let's say that C1 and C2 were swapped out with each other where C1 becomes C2 and C2 becomes C1.

Apparently the charging and discharging process is *work being done* because of charge being transferred and it appears to be equal to the initial 1 Joule of energy.

If this process was *repeated several times* by swapping out the C1 and C2 capacitors with each other then the work done *appears to be increasing* beyond the ability of the initial 1 Joule of energy.

I realize after several capacitor swaps that the original 1 Joule of energy will eventually decrease to a very low value due to losses from resistance, but in the meantime the work *appears* to be increasing as well as the *power* with each successive capacitor swap.

The energy required to swap out the capacitors is not included.

Is this possible? Is this true and if so why or why isn't this true?

Comment: Swapping the capacitors takes energy. This will quickly swamp whatever energy the circuit is "generating".

Comment: Hi, should I include in the question that the energy required to swap out the capacitors is not included?

Comment: It *has* to be. Your system is now larger than just the circuit itself; you can't ignore physics just because it's inconvenient.

Comment: It can do up to one joule of work.

Comment: Not gonna go to a different question to get pertinent information about this one.  On a separate topic, you are asking questions here which result from your fundamental confusion of work, power, and energy.  These are basic physics, not specifically electrical engineering.  Go back and learn the basic physics elsewhere.

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, I am not ignoring physics. I simply do not wish to include  the energy required to swap the capacitors around, because I am only interested in the processes of the energy transfer inside the circuit only. I do believe this is ok to do.

Comment: @ Olin Lathrop, I am slightly agitated that you think that I am fundamentally confused of work, power, and energy. Please explain how I am fundamentally confused about work, power, and energy. Electrical engineering and Physics are interrelated with each other and if you don't think they are please tell me how they aren't. I can not recreate the same question over and over and so I have created a completely new and different question. I see no problems with this. What else am I supposed to do right?

Comment: Swapping the capacitors *puts energy into the system*. The only way to ignore this energy is to not swap the capacitors.

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, The energy is already in the system and swapping capacitors I think would be an external energy as external forces are required to do that. The external force of swapping capacitors around does not add energy into the system that already has the internal energy contained.

Comment: That's still not how physics works. The system is now the circuit *plus whatever is swapping the capacitors*.

Comment: Ok fine you win. Just add in 8 solid state mosfet relay switches triggered by a 555 timer chip or some other kind of oscillator circuit.

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, actually if you really want to go that route then a simple transistor and resistor blocking oscillator will transfer the energy for you, and if the inductor was trifilar wound then the energy can be sent straight back to the C1 without any swapping involved, but that's out of the question originally posed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is .95J worth of work within 1 second Equivalent to .95W of Power?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/336654/is-95j-worth-of-work-within-1-second-equivalent-to-95w-of-power)

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a confusion between the physics concept of 'work', and several other meanings of 'work'.

If C1 starts off with 1J in it, and you transfer the energy losslessly between C1 and C2, then C1 will do 1J of work on C2. If you then transfer the energy back again, C2 does 1J of work on C1.

Do you think that that means 2J of work has been done? It appears that 1J of work has 'been done' twice. So what's going on?

The key is that the work has been done reversibly, which is a necessary condition if it's to be done losslessly. If we connected C1 and C2 with a resistor to equalise their voltages, then some work would be done irreversibly on the resistor. We would end up with 0.25J in each capacitor, and 0.5J of heat in the resistor, which gets lost to the environment.

However, if we connect C1 and C2 with a lossless inductor, and time the connection and disconnection events correctly, then we can move all the energy from one to the other. No work is done on the environment, all the work is done on the other capacitor, and that leaves the other capacitor *with the ability to do 1J of work*, which is exactly the same as saying that it has 1J of energy stored in it.

No work needs to be done on anything or by anything other than the two capacitors involved to move that energy between C1 and C2, in the ideal world that is.

If you want a simpler conceptual system where work is being done over and over again, consider a lossless pendulum. Work is done from the potential energy of the bob as it loses height on the kinetic energy of the bob, then back again.

To get any deeper than this, then you really need to head on over to the Physics stack, and ask about entropy, Carnot, thermodynamics, reversible processes etc.

Answer (score 1):

After yet more clarification via comments discussion, I think I understand how to answer the OP's question, which was ...

Q) We have a system of 2 capacitors and one inductor, where one capacitor is charged initially to 1J, and energy is then shuttled from one capacitor to the other via the inductor, when switched with suitable timing. How much total energy can be moved between the capacitors, if we count each energy transfer as positive?

A) First of all, let's simplify the system.

After the energy has been stored in the inductor, it does not matter whether it's returned to the same or a different capacitor. So, we'll return it to the same capacitor. This eliminates the complication of the suitably timed switch, as we can just consider an LC tank circuit that's resonating.

First deal with the lossless case. The positive energy moved accumulates to infinity, if we wait for an infinite time.

Next consider the lossy case. If the circuit has resistance, then for each cycle, a certain amount of energy will be lost as heat in the resistance, and the remainder will be stored again in the capacitor. Let's call this fraction returned to the capacitor \$\alpha\$.

If we start with 1J of energy stored, then after one cycle, the amount returned to the capacitor is \$\alpha J\$, we've lost \$(1-\alpha) J\$ to the resistance as heat, and we have done (in the OP's sense) \$\alpha J\$ of work within the system.

In the second cycle, we manage to return only \$\alpha^2 J\$ to the capacitor. The total work done is \$(\alpha + \alpha^2) J \$.

After three cycles, the OP's work done sums to \$(\alpha + \alpha^2 + \alpha^3) J \$.

Although (in classical physics at least) the oscillation will continue for ever, and so this is an infinite series, this series has a finite sum, and the sum S is \$S = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\$.

And this is the answer to the OP's question. If x fraction (say 5%) of the energy transferred is lost to resistance on each transfer, then a total magnitude of 1/x J (in the 5% case, 20J) will have been transferred, for an initial investment of 1J.

Note that in this time, the total lost in resistance, that is, moved outside the original system, is exactly 1J.

Quite what this 20J sum of energy transferred means physically, or whether it's worth calculating, is another matter. It's interesting, in a gee whizz sense, but that's all.

Comment: It's really time to give up on this OP.

Comment: @OlinLathrop It is indeed. But it's been interesting to try to figure out where he's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

After a long comment conversation, it's clear that the OP wants a different interpretation to this question.

Q) How much work is 1J of energy stored in a capacitor capable of doing?

A) The answer is an infinite amount of work. As long as we store the work it does in a different form, then return it losslessly so that it can be done again, and total up the magnitude of the work done, we can recycle this 1J of energy endlessly.

Unfortunately, work is a signed quantity, which rather makes a nonsense of accumulating its magnitude.

When C1 is doing work on C2 to move the 1J of energy from C1 to C2, the voltage and current define the flow of energy. When C2 moves the energy back to C1, one or the other of voltage and current reverses, the C1 to C2 work is now negative. The total work done by C1 on C2 is back to zero.

What this means is that what the rest of the world means by work, the movement of energy from one place to another, which is of course signed, and what the OP means by work, which appears to have some accounting convention where it can always be counted as positive for some reason, are different.

An analogy occurs to me, the way politicians might count the spending power of money spent on government infrastructure. The money is earned by a company, so counted as revenue. It's paid to the workers as wages, who spend in in local shops, so counted as revenue. The shop owners then spend it somewhere else, so it's counted as revenue. So the initial £1bn has created much more than £1bn revenue. Why do politicians do this? So it can be taxed, at every transfer from one person to another. What's the maximum tax that can be raised on an initial injection of £1bn into the economy? The answer is £1bn, no more.

Now let's look at lossy transfers from C1 to C2. Every transfer is 'taxed', by losing some energy in resistance. What's the maximum tax that can be extracted from this initial 1J of energy in C1? It's exactly 1J, no more. It doesn't matter whether each transfer loses 1mJ, and we make 1000 of them, or 1uJ and we make a million, that's the maximum resistance loss tax we can raise. According to the OP's accounting, in the first case we've made 1000 transfers of average 0.5J, shifting 500J, and in the second case 1000000 transfers shifting 500kJ. It's true, but physically meaningless.

In the continuing comment conversation, I made light of the fact that the OP was getting close to espousing free energy. I should have taken that more seriously at the time, because it does show up the flaw in his thinking. The comment he made was (my bolding) ...

> Ok then, you want to make it significant? You want to place a label on it? **Then try sticking a wheel with some magnets above the inductor and match the oscillations to it and witness the now meaningless work that has no physical significance to it perform even greater physical work**. But I digress, I do not wish to further complicate this seemingly simplistic, and meaningless and insignificant multiplication and magnification of energy, power, and work, all from the same 1 Joule of energy. Unless you want to continue to do so of course, then be my guest

A wheel with some magnets? That's a motor. That abstracts energy from the system. Let's say C1 does 1J of work, which consists of 10mJ to spin the magnet wheel, and 0.99J into the other capacitor. Now you have only 0.99J stored. Any more you take out in the next transfer reduces it further.

It doesn't matter how many transfers of energy are done, what magnitude of work has been performed backwards and forwards, only a maximum of 1J may be abstracted out into the wheel magnet indicator before the amount of stored energy becomes zero. It's meaningless to talk about the magnitude of work that shuttles back and forth, because it *can't do any more work on an external system than the amount of energy stored in the first system to begin with*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67872/discussion-on-answer-by-neil-uk-how-much-work-power-is-1-joule-of-energy-capable).

Comment: Don't care about external systems. Only you do.